# Copy Edge browser collections to different profile

Tags: microsoft-edge

I have many bookmarks in Edge browser stored in Edge Collections. These Collections are only visible within the current browser profile. I'd like to copy my Collections from my work browser profile to my personal browser profile.

Does Edge offer an easy way to copy Collections over to a different browser profile?

Comment: These different browser profiles existing or are they new?  If they are new you should be able to simply copy the contents of the original profile and copy them in the new profile directory

Comment: Both profiles exist and are rather "mature".

Answer (score 1):

You will find the Collections data stored in the folder
`%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Collections`
as SQLite database.

Copying the contents of the folder to another user's profile might work,
but I have never tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Used it and confirmed this does actually work, thanks.

Copied both `collectionsSQLite` and `collectionsSQLite-journal` files from

```
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Profile 1\Collections
```

to

```
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Profile 1\Collections
```

`collectionsSQLite-journal` was empty at the time but I still copied both files and it worked.